# DeadLetter exception on ask for multiple messgaes

Tags: scala, exception, actor

In the below code snippet, ControllerActor asks BackgroundActor for multiple messages. And the messages that are asked later are processed before the previously asked messages. But some how they are not delivered and result in DeadLetter Exception. Please find below code snippet :-

```
package pack

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import pack.ControllerActor.Msg

object ActorAskingMultipleMsgs {
  def main( args: Array[String] ): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem( "test-system" )
    val testActor = system.actorOf( Props[BackgroundActor], "testActor" )
    val controller = system.actorOf( ControllerActor.props( testActor ), "controller" )

    //second argument in Msg is the time
    //that is used in BackgroundActor to simulate delay
    controller ! Msg( "A", 8000 )
    controller ! Msg( "B", 6000 )
    controller ! Msg( "C", 1000 )

    Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
  }
}

object ControllerActor {
  case class Msg( msg: String, a: Int )
  def props( testActor: ActorRef ) = Props( new ControllerActor( testActor ) )
}

class ControllerActor( val af: ActorRef ) extends Actor {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  implicit val timeout = Timeout( 10 seconds )

  def receive = {
    case msg: Msg =>
      println( s"starting processing for msg $msg" )
      af ? msg map {
        case str: String =>
          println( s"data returned is $str" )
        case _ => println( "Invalid data is returned" )
      }
      println( s"finished processing for msg $msg" )

    case _ => println( "Unknown msg type in controller" )
  }
}

class BackgroundActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Msg( str, a ) =>
      println( s"processing of msg($str, $a) starts here" )
      Thread.sleep( a )
      println( s"processing of msg($str, $a) ends here" )
      sender ! str.toUpperCase()
    case _ =>
      println( "Unknown msg" )
      sender ! false
  }
}
```

Please suggest, what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the timeout in ControllerActor. Set it to something like:

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout( 20 seconds )
```

The reason is that ControllerActor is going to send all three messages immediately. And so, will create three futures. Since actors process messages one at a time, it's going to take, at least 8 + 6 = 14 seconds for BackgroundActor to send response to second message. Which is larger than what you set the timeout to.

Timeout exception will kill ControllerActor. That's why you get dead letters.